# How to embed cover art into MP4 without errors?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I want to add artwork to my MP4 file. How do I do this successfully / without errors?
I've tried these methods with numerous MP4 files, none worked.
If you would like to replicate the errors / bugs, here are the sample [files](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/29plag9akl9r1/61375246) I've used for this question.

I've tried the following:

---

1. `ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -disposition:v:0 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4`
   as stated by [Lukas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015965/12308353)

with this error:

```
[mp4 @ 0000019ee4852280] Could not find tag for codec h264 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

[ffmpeg 4.2.2](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-4.2.2-win64-static.zip) (Windows build by Zeranoe)

2. `atomicparsley sample.mp4 --artwork sample.png --overWrite`

with no success; [AtomicParsley](https://sourceforge.net/projects/atomicparsley/files/atomicparsley/AtomicParsley%20v0.9.0/AtomicParsley-win32-0.9.0.zip/download)

I get this message when executing the first time:

```
Started writing to temp file.
 Progress: =============================================>100%|
 Finished writing to temp file.
```

Executing the next (nth) time gives this:

```
Updating metadata...   completed.
```

3. Adding artwork through the *GUI Tag Editor* using both available versions: [i686-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-i686-w64-mingw32.exe.zip) & [x86_64-w64](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor/releases/download/v3.3.6/tageditor-3.3.6-x86_64-w64-mingw32.exe.zip)

with no success; it creates a *sample.mp4.bak* [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4kBR.png), even though the [software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Xt8.png) says that the operation was successful

> can't insert any more links, because I got too little rep apparently

4. Mp3tag (mp3tag.de/en)

with no success; I can successfully add the image as a cover, but it's not visible in the File Explorer. After saving it says *Saved tag in 1 of 1 files.* The [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs3ik.png) can been seen in Mp3tag though as if it's applied.

5. Tag&Rename (softpointer.com)

with no success; same story as with Mp3tag, I can apply and it's visible in the app, but not in File Explorer.

6. mp4v2 (https:// code.google.com/archive/p/mp4v2/downloads)

`mp4tags.exe -picture sample.png sample.mp4`

with no success; it executes with no (error)message

I found it on this thread

(https:// forum.videohelp.com/threads/388025-How-to-set-the-thumbnail-of-a-video-clip).

Have used the *updated* version which is the Windows build

(https:// forum.doom9.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=14314&d=1407985798).

7. iTunes

iTunes 12.10.6.2 (Microsoft Store version)

<s>iTunes doesn't load the file into the library.</s> I can run it fine though in QuickTime Player.

I didn't notice the 'Home Videos' tab. Now I can see it in there. I tried to apply the image, and it applied it only inside iTunes... So it's still not working for me.

I tried to convert the MP4 to M4A and then adding it to iTunes. I was **finally** successfully able to change the cover and it was visible in File Explorer. But that's not what I want.

I know for a fact that it's possible, because I've seen pictures on the Internet and YT and different threads where an answer is upvoted.

8. tag

https:// github.com/b4winckler/tag

The description is: *Simple command line audio tag editor*... After having to install millions of libraries and a package manager I was stuck with the compilation of the software, followed all the steps, didn't work.

I've also tried using MP4art as suggested by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27130727/12308353) on another issue about this. He didn't include a link to it so I went looking and found another issue about [this](https://superuser.com/q/656481/1127977). One comment recommended MP4art as well, with a link that's dead.

---

I believe I've used some other methods as well but can't think of them right now. Will update if I recall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the mac I use subler, https://subler.org, which works perfect. Looks like you're using Windows, but if you've got access to a mac, give that a try. I initially went looking for a tool to do this on Windows as well, came across subler, and there was no going back to anything Windows for this task after that.

Comment: I'm pretty discouraged to install a whole MacOS VM... after all the things I've tried. I also think it'd be crippling to launch the VM every time I want to update / add a cover... you know what I mean. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: If you don't have a mac I wouldn't necessarily go to that much trouble, I just happened to have both, and subler is the best tool I've found for this job by far. Usually you can find something on either platform, I'm not sure why there don't appear to be good Windows tools for the same task.

Comment: Well, the popular FFmpeg should do it just fine, but it doesn't, at least not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [*Codec Tweak Tool*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4snnj.png) under Miscellaneous > Thumbnails the checkbox for .mp4 was unchecked. After checking it and saving the settings it finally showed the thumbnail.

The Tweak Tool is installed with [**K-Lite Codec Pack**](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). There are different editions available, I use the Standard edition so I can't talk for the other ones.

Credits for finding the solution: [Furty](https://superuser.com/users/1165405/furty) from the same (copied) thread on Super User as a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1544737/how-to-embed-cover-art-into-mp4-without-errors?noredirect=1#comment2348563_1544737)

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -i sample.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy \
       -disposition:v:1 attached_pic sample_w_artwork.mp4
```

Just change `v:0` to `v:1`.